# Basic conditional probability question; find probability of a shared event

Tags: probability

> Consider two disjoint events $A_1$ and $A_2$.
>   Let $P(A_1) = 0.7$, $P(A_2) = 0.3$, $P(B|A_1) = 0.6$ and $P(B|A_2) = 0.2$.
>   What is the value of $P(A_1|B)$?

In order to find $P(A_1|B)$, I'll need to find $P(B)$, but I don't know how to do that in this case. It sounds like a basic question, with a simple answer, but I feel like I'm overlooking something...

Answer (score 1):

$$
P(B)=0.7\cdot0.6+0.3\cdot0.2=0.48\\
P(A_1\cap B)=0.42\\
P(A_1|B)=\frac{42}{48}=\frac{7}{8}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$P(B)=\sum P(B|A_i)P(A_i)$ where $A_i$ form a set of disjoint events whose union is the entire sample space. That's true because of the law of total probability. In your example, this is calculated as:

$$P(B)=P(B|A_1)P(A_1)+P(B|A_2)P(A_2)$$

Spoiler:

> $$P(B)=(0.6\times0.7)+(0.2\times0.3)=0.48$$

I assume you can work out $P(A_1|B)$ now that you have $P(B)$.